# how do I pixelate the face in ionic2 cameraApp?

Tags: ionic2, face-detection

I'm creating an app using ionic2 where it should detect the face and blur it. how can I do that? I checked OpenCV, ImageMagick & GraphicsMagick nothing helped!!

Answer (score 0):

I beleive OpenCV has face detection and I would then create a copy crop to the face area. Shrink and then scale back to original size. Put the pixelated image back over the original.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know much about OpenCV. I'll try that. hope it works in ionic app.